Early scholars view on the textual integrity of previous revelations
Assalamualaikum,
I had a question about which of the early scholars believed that the injeel and Torah had been corrupted in its texts. I have seen a few Hadiths from ibn Abbas (ra) saying the text is corrupted but there is also one which states that none can change the words of Allah. I was wondering if anyone could possibly send me a list of early scholars sayings on this topic.
Jazakallah Khair, May Allah bless you all.

Since the qur'an already confirms they are (partially) corrupted what do you expect anybody to claim?
